# Meeting gedolim in EY

Tags: blessing

does anyone have any addresses or Shiurim on where to meet gedolim in Eretz Yisroel? I am hoping to meet Rav Gershon Edelstein, R' Shalom Arush, R' Asher Weiss, The Yanuka, Rav Itche Meir Morgenstern etc. If anyone knows any about their Shabbos Tish it would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't think there's a "shiur" on how to meet gedolim. Just go to their shul and ask.

Comment: These people are usually pretty busy doing important things. They aren't tourist attractions. If you have a good reason to bother them then go ahead.

Comment: Or get in touch with their attendants and arrange a meeting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because publicly posting personal addresses is dangerous and should not be done on this platform

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt those who have the phone numbers and addresses of these gedolim are not going to share them publicly

Answer (score 1):

Every single figure you named in your question either has his own yeshiva or is associated with a yeshiva. Go to their yeshivas and find out when they will be giving over a shiur!